# Unable to set angularVelocity on element in A-Frame

Tags: aframe

I'm having trouble finding the right way to set the angular velocity on an object in a-frame.

```
<script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent("cuberotator", {
      init: function () {
        console.log("trying to rotate the cube...");
        const theta = new THREE.Vector3(0, 20, 0);
        console.log (theta);
        this.el.setAttribute('angularVelocity', theta);
        //where is angularVelocity attribute?
      }
    });
  </script>
```

I've attached a CodePen example at https://codepen.io/mcanterel/pen/LroRYz

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to rotate the cube around a certain point, you'd have to rotate the points frame of reference.

```
 <a-entity>
    <a-box></a-box>
 </a-entity>
```

You can move the cube as you wish, and by rotating the wrapper entity, the cube will rotate around its initial center.

---

Your component can set the rotation in the tick() function which is called each frame.

```
 tick: function() {
   let rot = this.el.getAttribute("rotation")
   rot.y += this.velocity // increase it on click or whenever
   this.el.setAttribute("rotation", rot)
  }
```

Comment: Two problems: 1- Your tick function works if I hard code in the velocity var, but this.el.getAttribute("velocity") doesn't work. 2- if I hard code in a val for y rotation (rot.y += 0.2 ), the component works on the a-box element, but not on the a-entity I created. Would you mind looking at the CodePen and give me your take?

Comment: @MCanterel try using the entitys schema: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYwEmw

Comment: Thanks for helping with the schema, but in your Pen, box1 still doesn't rotate. Is there something in the a-entity (or its mixin) that won't let me attach the cuberotator component?